# similar function to "static Criterion isNull(String propertyName) " for set not for String?

Tags: jakarta-ee

I meet a problem. 
The relationship between two tables is One-to-many, but unfortunately we just care the "ONE" whose "MANY " is null.

**The task is :**
Now I need to query the mice whose' Set should be null.
If hibernate can support "static Criterion isNull(Set s) ", then it is ok.

Other methods are also ok.

There are two Classes:

**Class 1:**

```
public class Mouse {
@OneToMany(mappedBy="mouse")
@Cascade(org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.LOCK)
@Where(clause="incage = 0")
private Set<Residency> cageHistory = new HashSet<Residency>();


@OneToMany(mappedBy="mouse")
@Cascade(org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.LOCK)
@Where(clause="incage = 1")
private Set<Residency> currentResidencies = new HashSet<Residency>();

...
...
```

}

**Class 2:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="smcagemouse")
public class Residency extends TimestampedEntity implements Serializable {
@Column(nullable=false)
/*0 -- not active*/
/*1 -- active*/
```

}

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This can be soveled by isNotEmpty().

Restrictions.isNotEmpty(propertyName);

I have realized the solution.